# How to get new image (from array) after start activity?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have button which starts the same activity. How can I get next image from array, **after** start activity? Here is code of button

```
Button btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }

            });
```

Here is array

```
int[] array_images = {
            R.drawable.apple,
            R.drawable.p_dolor
    };
```

Comment: where is you array with image ?

Comment: @Sree just added, it is default image array

Comment: Is it totally necessary to restart the activity by calling `finish();` - what happens if you rotate the screen and the Activity is recreated anyway as part of the normal lifecycle.  Can you just not cycle through the images using a button and some logic, and save the position in the array (image to display) in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore that image in `onCreate`?

Comment: @MarkKeen it's a piece of code, I have to use  finish(); with startActivity(getIntent());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you exactly want to restart activity every-time, You can just change your resource on button click without Restarting the activity. For example -

```
int index = 0;
int[] imgRes = {R.id.image1, R.id.image2, R.id.image3, R.id.image4};
    Button btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    updateImage();
                }

            });
private void updateImage(){
    index++;
    if(index >= imgRes.lenght)
        index = 0;
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    imageView.setResource(imgRes[index])
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks its works, but is there any way to combine updateImage(); and startActivity(getIntent());?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but restarting activity is not a good code practice. Because restarting activity create an another instance of the activity that will take extra memory and user experience will be not also good. You can do everything without restarting an activity then its then better to do without restarting it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one you have to manage array indexing for that like below:-

```
int index = 0;
int[] array_images = {R.id.image1, R.id.image2, R.id.image3, R.id.image4};
 Button btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
                    setImageRes();
 btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    setImageRes();
                }

            });


 private void setImageRes(){
        index++;
        if(index < array_images.lenght){
            imageView.setResource(array_images[index])
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int index = 0;
int[] array_images = {R.id.image1, R.id.image2};
Button btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
setImageRes(getIntent().getIntExtra());

btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               index = getIntent().getIntExtra();
               dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,CallActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position",index++);
            }
        });

 private void setImageRes(int position){
        imageView.setResource(array_images[position])
     }
```

Comment: CallActivity? I use only one activity

Comment: keep the name of the activity you are using on the place of CallActivity. It denotes that you are getting redirected to the same activity.